# How to extract text from Pdf using Pypdf2 excluding the text content from Charts and Tables

Tags: python, text, pypdf

I want to extract text content from PPT and PDF files in python.

While using PPTX works fine for extracting the text, using PyPDF2 extracts the text content from charts and tables as well from PDF when using extract_text() which I don't want.

I have tried different things but can't figure out a way to achieve this. Is there any way that this can be done? Pfb the code for the same.

```
import ntpath 
import os 
import glob 
import PyPDF2 
import pandas as pd from pptx import Presentation

        df_header=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Document_Name', 'Document_Type', 'Page_No', 'Text', 'Report Name'])
df_header.to_csv('Downloads\\\\FinalSample.csv', mode='a', header=True) 
for eachfile in glob.glob("D:\\CP US People-Centric Hub (19-SCP-3063)\\Reports\\/*\\\\/*"):
    file1 = eachfile.split("\\")
    report_name = file1[3]
    if eachfile.endswith(".pptx"):
        data=[]
        prs = Presentation(eachfile)
        for slide in prs.slides:
            text_runs = ''
            slide_num = prs.slides.index(slide) + 1
            for shape in slide.shapes:
                if not shape.has_text_frame:
                    continue
                for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
                    text_runs = text_runs + ' ' + paragraph.text
            data.append([ntpath.basename(eachfile), 'PPT', slide_num, text_runs,report_name])      
        df_ppt=pd.DataFrame(data)
        df_ppt.to_csv('Downloads\\\\FinalSample.csv', mode='a', header=False)  
    elif eachfile.endswith(".pdf"):
        data1=[]
        pdfFileObj = open(eachfile, 'rb')
        pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)
        outlines = pdfReader.getOutlines()
        for pageNum in range(pdfReader.numPages):
            data1.append([ntpath.basename(eachfile), 'PDF', pageNum + 1,pdfReader.getPage(pageNum).extractText(),report_name])
        df_pdf=pd.DataFrame(data1)
        df_pdf.to_csv('Downloads\\\\FinalSample.csv', mode='a', header=False)
        pdfFileObj.close()
```

Comment: Remember Text in only supplementary data in PDF. It may appear in random order or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry: extracting *just* the body text from a PDF and omitting figure titles, footnotes, headers, footers, page numbers etc. isn't possible in general. This is because "body text" isn't really a defined concept in the PDF format.

You could however dig into the library and add some heuristics targeting figure captions e.g. to discard blocks of text that follow a large gap without text, or are too short (but what about titles?), or perhaps where the font size is much smaller than the mean.